# Removing duplicates from a nested list

Tags: python

I am trying to get a new list called `new_colors` where it only has `[['orange', 'green'], ['purple', 'red']]`, removing the duplicates from my original list `colors`. For example, `'orange'` is repeated twice in two different lists.

```
colors = [
    ['orange', 'green'],
    ['orange', 'yellow'],
    ['purple', 'red'],
    ['brown', 'red']]
```

this is what I came up with but it is not working.

```
new_colors = []

for i in colors:
  if i not in new_colors:
    new_colors.append(i)

print(new_colors)
```

Comment: What if you had an extra item `['red', 'black']`, would you want to keep it?

Answer (score 2):

You can define and sequentially update a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) `seen` that stores elements seen, and use `in` combined with `any` to test whether a sublist has any element that is in `seen`:

```py
colors = [['orange', 'green'], ['orange', 'yellow'], ['purple', 'red'], ['brown', 'red']] 

seen = set()
output = []
for sublst in colors:
    if not any(x in seen for x in sublst):
        output.append(sublst)
        seen.update(sublst)

print(output) # [['orange', 'green'], ['purple', 'red']]
```

Comment: Depending on OP's specific requirements, they might want to dedent `.update()`, for example if you add `['yellow', 'blue']` to the end of `colors`, this method will include it, but dedented will exclude it.

Comment: @wjandrea Oh thanks! But I am afraid I am too drunk now to process it now... Let's leave it to OP.... Cheers!

Comment: @wjandrea Oh now I get it! Thanks again for the suggestion. But as the requirement is ambiguous, I'll leave it to the OP. But thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As your example is ambiguous, I am providing here a solution to track the duplicates independently over the "columns". This means, if you had an extra `['red', 'black']` it would be kept as `red` is unique in the first column.

```
new_colors = []
seen = [set() for i in range(len(colors))]

for l in colors:
    # check if any item was already picked
    if any(e in s for e,s in zip(l,seen)):
        continue
    new_colors.append(l)
    # update picked items
    for e,s in zip(l,seen):
        s.add(e)

print(new_colors)
```

Output:

```
[['orange', 'green'],
 ['purple', 'red']]
```

Answer (score 0):

More or less based on @j1-lee's answer, you could wrap the whole thing in a generator. Iterate over the color groups, and generate a set for each. If there exists an intersection between the current color set, and the set of all previously seen colors, do nothing. Otherwise, yield the current group and update the set of previously seen colors:

```
colors = [
    ['orange', 'green'],
    ['orange', 'yellow'],
    ['purple', 'red'],
    ['brown', 'red']
]

def to_filtered(groups):
    seen = set()
    for current_set, current_group in zip(map(set, groups), groups):
        if not seen & current_set:
            yield current_group
            seen |= current_set

print(list(to_filtered(colors)))
```

Output:

```
[['orange', 'green'], ['purple', 'red']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
colors = [
    ['orange', 'green'],
    ['orange', 'yellow'],
    ['purple', 'red'],
    ['brown', 'red']]
    
new_colors = []
isUnique = True

for pair in colors:
    unique_colors = [new_color for new_pair in new_colors for new_color in new_pair]
    for color in pair:
        if color in unique_colors:
            isUnique = False
            break
    if isUnique == True:
        new_colors.append(pair)
    isUnique = True

print(new_colors)
```

So,here first I declare an additional variable `isUnique` as flag and using a new list `unique_colors` which is inside the outer for loop, it is a flattened version of `new_colors` list and it will update each time new unique `pair` of color added to `new_colors` list.

Then inside the inner for loop, a checking took place for each color of the current `pair`. here if any `color` of the current `pair` matches any color of the `unique_colors` list, `isUnique` will be set `False`, and the inner loop will break.

After that `isUnique` will be checked and if it's `True` then the current `pair` will be added to `new_colors` and at the very last `isUnique` is to be set `True` for the next iteration.

Output : `[['orange', 'green'], ['purple', 'red']]`